# Seeing report filters in other account of odoo?

Tags: odoo, access-rights

I added a user to my Odoo. I want this user to see the reports filter! But I couldn't find out how to!! Here is the difference between my account and his account. He is my supervisor, So I must give him the permission to see what I see
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click button shown in below image. Filter will appear.

[image: Filter show/hide]